# Connection with Linux client to VPN azure giving up

Tags: linux, vpn, azure

I'm trying to connect from a Linux to a VPN in Azure.

I can connect in windows clients and am trying to setup the client in Linux

I followed the instructions in [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-openvpn-clients) but i cannot stablish a connection, when I try to up the connection the server not respond.

```
ipsec up my_azurevpn
retransmit 5 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 192.168.0.7[500] to 1.2.3.4[500] (1128 bytes)
giving up after 5 retransmits
peer not responding, trying again (2/3)
initiating IKE_SA azure_fudea[2] to 1.2.3.4
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
sending packet: from 192.168.0.7[500] to 1.2.3.4[500] (1128 bytes)
retransmit 1 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 192.168.0.7[500] to 1.2.3.4[500] (1128 bytes)
retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 192.168.0.7[500] to 1.2.3.4[500] (1128 bytes)
retransmit 3 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 192.168.0.7[500] to 1.2.3.4[500] (1128 bytes)
retransmit 4 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 192.168.0.7[500] to 1.2.3.4[500] (1128 bytes)
retransmit 5 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 192.168.0.7[500] to 1.2.3.4[500] (1128 bytes)
```

My ipsec.conf file is:

```
conn my_azurevpn
      keyexchange=ikev2
      type=tunnel
      leftfirewall=yes
      left=%any
      leftauth=eap-tls
      leftid=%client # use the DNS alternative name prefixed with the %
      right=mygatewayid.vpn.azure.com
      rightid=%mygatewayid.vpn.azure.com
      rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
      leftsourceip=%config
      auto=add
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. But I guess it's because the tutorials are not explicit enough. I have an azure virtual network gateway basic, and according to this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about) only SSTP connections are supported.
The configuration for SSTP is not working(probably because of the network-manager-sstp client), but the tutorial in the link you provided is for IKEv2 connections which are nmconnection files in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections